# RewriteCond works sometimes

Tags: linux, windows, apache, mod-rewrite

This is my code on /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dynamic-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>            
            DocumentRoot "/var/www/SITE.com.br"
            ServerName SITE.com.br

                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 10\.10\.10\.[0-255]
                RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://SITE.com.br/ [R=301]
```

My problem is, in some cases it's force to HTTPS, but in other cases it's not.
Example: On some desktops browsers, it's redirect to HTTPS, but on mobile browsers or on others desktops/servers browsers, it's not.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Why do you have a _condition_ that limits the redirect to "some" IP addresses? (That regex is certainly "wrong", but why is it there in the first place?)

Comment: Because when a connection come from outside, it's already in HTTPS, so I don't want that redirect again, therefore just redirect inside connections.

Comment: What do you mean? Why would be a connection HTTPS when it comes from outside? HTTPS means HTTP over TLS, see [Wikipedia: HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS): it says "The Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) scheme HTTPS has identical usage syntax to the HTTP scheme. However, HTTPS signals the browser to use an added encryption layer of SSL/TLS to protect the traffic." (i.e. use port 443), so only if a user enters "https://" on to their browser, it use HTTPS, i.e. not all connections from outside are HTTPS

Comment: If a connection that comes from outside is "already in HTTPS" then this directive is not processed at all, so the condition is entirely superfluous. (But what forces an external connection to be HTTPS?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, but I am not so sure that this will fix your issue:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>            
            DocumentRoot "/var/www/SITE.com.br"
            ServerName SITE.com.br

                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.10\.10\.
                RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://SITE.com.br/ [R=301]
```

I am not really sure why you are using `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}`, do you know that it actually makes the HTTP to HTTPS redirect happen only on remote IP addresses  (the IP address of the client) from 10.10.10.0 to 10.10.10.255? And there is a very huge possibility that the mobile phones have IP addresses that are outside 10.10.10, like 10.10.11.123!

**If you want to redirect to HTTPS for any IP address,** try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>            
            DocumentRoot "/var/www/SITE.com.br"
            ServerName SITE.com.br

                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://SITE.com.br/ [R=301]
```

You can also simplify `^(.+)$` in `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://SITE.com.br/ [R=301]` to `RewriteRule ^ https://SITE.com.br/ [R=301]`. Since '^(.+)' means "match and store everything that is in the current line", it uses more memory (RAM), `^` doesn't really store anything in memory.

Comment: Error occurred:

Syntax error on line 32 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-dynamic-vhosts.conf:
RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

In this line:
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.10\.10\.(\\d{1, 2}|(0|1)\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$

Comment: @Nicolas try now

Comment: It worked! Thank you.

Comment: @Nicolas, and feel free to ask me for help, for any other issues

Comment: Help me in this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70354156/err-ssl-obsolete-version